# Get Increment from Sequence in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In a SQL database I can get the increment value of a sequence:

```
select increment from sys.sequences where name = 'XXX';
```

Is there a way to do this for a sequence in an Oracle database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The corresponding table in Oracle is `all_sequences` (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2053.htm)):

```
select increment_by
from all_sequences
where sequence_name = 'XXX'
and sequence_owner = 'SCHEMANAME';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select increment_by from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'XXX'
```

Depending on what user you login as and which schema the sequence is in, you might need to query dba_sequences or all_sequences instead.